# 1-1 correspondence between $Hom_K(U,V)$ and $K^{m,n}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

The title says it all, I'm looking for a conclusive proof of the existence of this 1-1 correspondence.

I'm aware that each linear map over a field $K$ determines a unique matrix in $K^{m,n}$, but I'm a bit troubled by the converse. Although I think I understand it, I'm not sure how to put it concisely.

I'm guessing that we must show for each $K^{m,n}$ matrix, a unique linear map exists.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{HINT:}$ If $A \in K^{n,m}$ then the map you are looking is left-multiplication by $A$, namely $L_A: U \rightarrow V, x \mapsto xA$.

Comment: Could also be right-multiplication.